# How can I search within pdf content?

Tags: indexing

We used recoll with a desktop PC for searching between PDF-s. In the last week we moved everything to a server. Is there alternative recoll solution for server. We would like to index PDF files and by using a web interface searching among them?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643438/how-to-search-contents-of-multiple-pdf-files)?

Comment: This is not good, I would like to have a web gui, therefore others in our group can search within the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either index the files through the mounted file system, if it is acceptable, or index on the server and use the Recoll webui: https://github.com/koniu/recoll-webui

jf

Comment: I am getting the following error: recoll: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: You simply install recoll rather than use the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

[DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) may be worth a look, especially if the web interface is not absolutely necessary.